# How add URL or IMAGE-URL in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qurl

I have a `QString`, for example "https://google.com", I should convert from `QString` to `QUrl` and then add that `QUrl` in `QTextEdit`, when i click that URL, it will open https://google.com.

The next question is, is it possible to make an IMAGE-URL?
For example: if “https://example.com” opens a clothing site, can I add an IMAGE-URL to `QTextEdit` so when I click on this image it will open https://example.com, where IMAGE is image of clothes that opens https://example.com

Comment: welll you are just requesting a link the user can click.... so why dont you just use a QLabel... if no edition is required then no need for an edit widget, dont you think?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ, yeah, i think so, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Use `QLabel`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html

Example:

```
label->setText("<a href=\"http://example.com/\">Click Here!</a>");
label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
```